# iOS Development - Build for distribution and Custom Framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm having a problem with a custom framework and iOS 12.5.1.

XCode Version 12.4

iOS Version 12.5.1 - iPhone 5S

The problem is, when i build the framework with Build for distribution = NO it builds and I can usee it on my app, everything works well, when I build the framework with Build for distribution = YES I have an error:

```
Unknown class _exampleClass in Interface Builder file.

Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x2736dd2b0) to 'mySDK.myCustomClass' (0x1026a5008).

2021-04-06 15:43:14.709001+0100 MyApp[822:200663] Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x2736dd2b0) to 'mySDK.myCustomClass' (0x1026a5008).
```

Said problem only happens on ios 12.5.1 and with Build for Distribution = YES. On ios 13 or 14 it works great, and if I use Build for Distribution = NO it works on all devices with all ios versions.

Any lights??? Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Could you post some code? How is `mySDK.myCustomClass` set up? Also, is `mySDK.myCustomClass` targeting something that simply doesn't exist in iOS 12.5?

Comment: Hey, the custom class is a simple class that extends UIViewController. It does nothing special as it only handles some custom navigation protocols. As I said, if I use Build for Distribution as NO it works, so I do not think its related to targeting something that doesn't exist on ios 12.5.